# display a <img> from php( problem)

Tags: php

I wanna return a link inside to `<img>`. I dont know what is the problem.

categoria.php

```
<HTML>....
<img  src="categoriaMAIN.php?type=celular">
</HTML>
```

categoriaMAIN.php

```
<?php
$varcate= $_GET['type'];
if ($varcate == "celular")
   echo "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41l1yyZuyXL._AA160_.jpg";
?>
```

Comment: one way is to give an image header on the php page and show the image itself with php. i did that with the captcha i wrote ;)

Comment: /me liked that `(problem)` on the title

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**categoriaMAIN.php**

```
<?php

  switch ($_GET['type'])
  {
    case 'celular':
      header('Location: http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41l1yyZuyXL._AA160_.jpg');
      break;
    case '...':
      header('Location: http://somesite.com/some/img/path/image.jpg');
      break;
    //...
  }
```

*Everyone else seemed to offer the readfile/grab and forward the content method. I thought I'd let the HTTP protocol do the work for us.*

Comment: Yeah, your solution its better, more fast when u wanna change of parameters. THNX

Answer (score 3):

Well, the img tag is pointing to text, not an image.

Try:

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpg"); //tell the browser that this is an image.
$varcate= $_GET['type']; // you know this part
if ($varcate == "celular")
{
   // readfile will grab the file and then output its contents without 
   // procressing it.
   readfile("http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41l1yyZuyXL._AA160_.jpg");
}
```

Bit of a warning: if you don't output an image here, then the browser will probably complain about the image it is trying to load. You should add a default.

### EDIT

Kristian made the point that this is a lot of work for the server and he is right. It would be much better if you could manage to make it so that the src of the img tag changed directly. The above, however, will get you where you are asking to go, though it may not be the best option.

Comment: It is a lot of extra server load/bandwidth to force the server to download the image just to show it to the user - what you are doing is actually making a proxy.

Comment: Its good, tnx, and this is big warning ;). althought its display slowly

Answer (score 0):

The `img` tag has to point at the actual image - not a webpage containing the URL.

```
<img src="categoriaMAIN.php?type=celular">
```

has to get evalulated to

```
<img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41l1yyZuyXL._AA160_.jpg">
```

It isn't being right now. How to accomplish this, greatly depends on the rest of your source code and what you actually are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work! `<img src=""` searches for the image file, not its location! Try this:

#### categoria.php

```
<?php $varcate='celular'; ?>
<html>....
<img src="<?php include('categoriaMAIN.php'); ?>">
</html>
```

#### categoriaMAIN.php

```
<?php
if ($varcate == "celular")
   echo "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41l1yyZuyXL._AA160_.jpg";
?>
```

Comment: giving a header and using `readfile` really would be a better option than an include :)

Comment: @Achshar Sounds true, but wouldn't the PHP compiler spend time processing the `readfile` function?

Comment: similar (maybe more [not sure]) time will be spent `including` the file. Genrel idea is to avoid includes when possible plus if it is in loop then php will cache `readfile` but wont cache include

Comment: @Achshar Really? I give up. Going to test it.

Comment: so, I have to do several .php for each categoria, cuz Imnot use method with parameters

Comment: @A3R no, there is that `if` statement, you can add as many image sources as you want in single file..

Comment: @A3R You're using $varcate. And I **do** think that the answer you chose is better. @Achshar `INCLUDE (php) 0.000887;
READFILE (png) 0.001515` (http://pastebin.com/EErUYWzd)

Comment: and how I will fill $varcate ? if i dont have parameters.

Comment: @A3R Every time you want to show an image you have to set `$varcate`... (in **categoria.php**). As you can see, there are numerous ways to solve the same problem, something that shows how flexible PHP is.

Answer (score 0):

You give the `img` a PHP page as its `src`. So the browser is expecting that PHP page to return an image. Instead, you're having that page simply return a URL to the image. You'll have to change that so that you're actually `echo` ing the image data. I'm a little rusty will all this, but I think you'd do something like the following:

```
<?php
$varcate = $_GET['type'];
if ($varcate == 'celular') {
    header('Content-type: image/jpg');
    echo file_get_contents('http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41l1yyZuyXL._AA160_.jpg');
}
?>
```

Comment: It is a lot of extra server load/bandwidth to force the server to download the image just to show it to the user - what you are doing is actually making a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it this way, your `categoriaMAIN.php` would need to look more like:

```
<?php
$varcate = $_GET['type'];
if ($varcate == "celular") {
    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    echo file_get_contents("http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41l1yyZuyXL._AA160_.jpg");
}
?>
```

This will get the actual image data and return it to the browser as an image, which is what the browser needs.