# calling another php file using <img> tag

Tags: php, image

image.html -
`<img src="showImage.php?id=44"/>`  <-- this is the code I'm trying to make work.

showImage.php -
`<?php  echo ("showImage.php called");   ?>` <-- this is the php file I'm trying to call.

The problem is.. img tag is not calling 'showImage.php' to print out "showImage.php called.". Instead, it tries to display showImage.php file as an image :( ... and doesn't display what it's supposed to. Am I doing something wrong here?

*Note: id=44 will be used for something else... not a big concern here.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's what an `<img>` tag does. It displays images. It cannot expand into normal page flowtext if the server sends an invalid image file.

Comment: What @mario says - this is the indended behaviour. Can you elaborate on what you want to achieve with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [display a <img> from php( problem)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588169/display-a-img-from-php-problem)

Comment: You need to return proper image with proper header for it to do what you want

Comment: Maybe you would want to use an `<iframe>` here?

Comment: Thank you guys. :)  I was not aware of that.  Yeah. I was trying to get a blog image to display but before writing full codes, I wanted to make sure <img src=...> tag calls a php file properly.. and that was why this issue came up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually visit that page in the browser, I'm sure it will print out `showImage.php called` in the browser. However, you're specifying that the file should be an image in your HTML and the browser is trying to treat it as an image. When it gets a text/html file instead, the browser merely shows that the image was invalid, it does not print the text instead. Your showImage.php will need to actually output an image in order for the browser to render it inside your document. Otherwise, you'll have to visit the page manually to see any text it's outputting for debugging, etc.

All in all, it *is* calling your file, the browser is just ignoring the result. It will *never* show text instead of an image, unless you specify an `alt` attribute.

Comment: Many tutorials dealing with blog images didn't point out that fact.  I was learning and doing step by step to debug... and being so careful was why this kind of issue came up...  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

`<img/>` will try to display things as an image, it's kind of it's purpose ;-)

You'll need to make `showImage.php` output an image/image data. You can do this dynamically in PHP with GD2 or imagemagick.

This is an example of how to [write text using GD2, from the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php).

```
<?php
// Set the content-type
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = 'Testing...';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'arial.ttf';

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks I was testing if <img src="..."/> stuff works fine before writing full codes... and being very careful caused such troubles :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an image using the GD Library in `showimage.php` and set the headers to that file to `image/png`, or whatever image type it is.